# Best way to create this list based off table

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a table that has multiple inputs and I would like to know how I could transfer this over to a list in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

It is as follows

```
Name of Sport                                 Slowest Time       Fastest Time      Comments
Soccer on the ground really long field name     100s                   200s         Played well
Cricket                                         150s                   300s         Could have played better
```

Each sport will be the same for each user. It is just the Times and Comments that will be different. What is the best way to set this out as a list? When someone views the list, I would like to display it back to them like this, with the sports in that order.

Should I have a lookup column with the different sports (even though some of the values are going to be quite long (~50 characters) and have the others as string inputs? Then when it comes time to display it back to the user, just order them how I need them?

**EDIT:** I have been doing a bit more thinking and I am just wondering, as Name of Sport will be the same for each user, could I hard code those into the view and somehow associate the Slowest Times and Fastest Times with the Name of Sport? That way, the user does not need to pick the Name of Sport each time.

Cheers,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lookup for `Name of Sport` is OK.

For `Slowest Time` and `Fastest Time`, you can use strings or numbers. Numbers seem to fit better, but in this case you'll have to [apply CSR for this field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220061(v=office.15).aspx) in order to show the additional "s" at the end.

Sorting:

1. You can create an extra column e.g. `Order`, put numbers there according to your sorting preference, and then setup the view to order by that column. The `Order` column can be of course excluded from the view itself.
2. If you create a list of type "Links", it already has this kind of functionality in UI: [image]

Comment: Thank-you for your fast response Andrey.

I have been doing a bit more thinking and I am just wondering, as Name of Sport will be the same for each user, could I hard code those into the view and somehow associate the Slowest Times and Fastest Times with the Name of Sport? That way, the user does not need to pick the Name of Sport each time.

Comment: You can associate times with the sport, just put them into same table, and when you create the lookup, check the boxes for these fields to be shown along with the sports name. But regarding `user does not need to pick the Name of Sport each time` I don't understand. Can you explain in a bit more detail the process you have? E.g. who adds what and what is the purpose of all this...

Comment: Apologies for not explaining myself better. Basically,  I have a table like: http://i.imgur.com/zn9S7kY.png   The names of the sports do not change. Everyone that uses the system has to add times against every sport. I am wondering, would it be OK to hard code the names of the sports into the add new item to list form, then have columns in SharePoint like: Soccer_Slowest_Time, Cricket_Slowest_Time, Football_Slowest_Time etc. So in an essence, my add new item list form would look something like this: http://i.imgur.com/sACj3Vm.png

Where everything in italics is a field in SP

Comment: Unfortunately that's still a puzzle :( You're concentrating on the immediate problem, but in order to give a valuable advice, I need a bit more of a background.

Comment: One variant that makes some sense I came up based on your descriptions is that you have e.g. competitions for different age ranges/seasons/colleges/whatever other category, and you store statistical values for each of these. But then, I don't understand how you display those data - meaning how list view would look like. It is important, because e.g. if you plan to use grouping or filtering, this might affect ordering approaches. Also, if you embed sports names into field names, then displaying such a huge table can become a big problem.

Comment: Usually in SharePoint it makes a lot of sense to distance yourself from the problem and find the most suitable way to solve the whole thing. It could be e.g. that we might reuse JSGrid webpart or even basic Excel documents in a library or Access form or whatever else.

Comment: Took this information to manager. Approved. Cheers!!